# Android on click menu style

Tags: android, colors, menu, background, styles

I have a problem with my menu style. When I perform a click on a menu item, a rectangle surrounds the text of the item and I have currently not found how to change this.

Anyone know how to change that ?

Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXcJO.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link is being styled when it gains focus from your click. Reset the colours with something like:

```
a {background-color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {background-color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {background-color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {background-color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

You'll need to adjust the colour appropriately